# How is std::string_view constructed from an std::string?

Tags: c++, c++17

Looking at the [cppreference documentation for std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view), I see it defines 4 constructors in C++17:

```
constexpr basic_string_view() noexcept;
constexpr basic_string_view(const basic_string_view& other) noexcept = default;
constexpr basic_string_view(const CharT* s, size_type count);
constexpr basic_string_view(const CharT* s);
```

However, none of these take an std::string, so how is it possible to write code like this?

```
std::string s = "Hello";
std::string_view view(s);
```

Implementing my own string view class, and adding mock constructors which match all the standard ones, gives a compiler error:

```
struct sview {
    sview() {}
    sview(const sview &other) {}
    sview(const char* s, size_t count) {}
    sview(const char* s) {}
};

std::string s = "Hello";
std::string_view view(s); // ok
sview my_view(s); // no viable constructor
```

So how does it work? Is there special code in `std::string` to allow this conversion?

Comment: You are correct that there is no `std::string_view` constructor that takes a `std::string` as input.  But, `std::string` does indeed have its own [implicit conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view) to convert a `std::string` to a `std::string_view`.